# how to stop google chrome cache mechanism

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to stop/kill  the cache mechanism of google chrome browser when I am doing css and js work around a page

there is a trick 
you can open chrome devtools and since the devtools is open 
then cache mechanism is disable (it has config in setting section )

is there any plugin or extension for google chrome to stop/kill caching

I google around and find [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en)

but it does not work for me

my google chrome version is  46.0.2490.80

Comment: Have you tried the icognito mode?

Comment: @OdaYukimura that is not good choice because when you build and run your site visual studio automatically will open chrome in normal mode not in incognito mode

Comment: Ok :); but next time mention something like this in your question and here is a way to do this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioWebDevelopmentTipAddChromeIncognitoModeAsABrowser.aspx

Comment: @OdaYukimura can we consider your solution as best practice ? when you use a plugin it could easily be set off or on . i think plugin would be better choice.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings on google chrome you have

> Disable cache (while DevTools is open)

[image]

Comment: i do not want to keep the Dev Tools open since i am doing css and js work

Comment: You can "pop-out" the dev tools so that it doesn't block your view